# How to delete all the folders named __tests which is located in multiple directories?

Tags: node.js, bash

I have a folder named ***__tests*** for each project. I want to delete all the ***__tests*** folders at once in all the projects.

Comment: Do you want to do it using nodejs or using bash ?

Comment: anything is fine

Comment: Have a look at the `find` command.

Comment: @upender finding everywhere can take a lot of time, do you have a specific directory that encompasses all your projects ?

Comment: Yes I have all the projects in single directory

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution in bash

```sh
for dir in .*/initial/src/__tests; do
    rm -rf "$dir"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a one liner for this using `find` -

```
find /home/user/single_directory/ -type d -name "__tests" | xargs rm -rf
```

Comment: ok, thanks.
I missed telling you that inside that single directory for each project there are 2 `__tests` folders 1 in initial and the other in final.

Comment: Some (most?) versions of `find` have a `-delete` option.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a node.js implementation to delete the folder `__tests`. You give it the root directory you want to scan as a `DIRECTORY` variable and it will start scanning everything in it.

If you want to include multiple directories add them in `DIRECTORIES` variable.

```
const path = require("path");
const fs = require("fs");

// base directory you want to scan for the directory to be deleted
const DIRECTORY = "./test"; // single directory
const DIRECTORIES = ['dir-1', 'dir-2', 'dir-3']; // multiple directories

const removeMultipleDirs = function(dirs) {
    dirs.forEach(dir => {
        removeDir(dir);
    })
}

const removeDir = (baseDir) => {
    const absolutePath = getAbsolutePath(baseDir);

    try {
        // returns a string of files and directory in absolute path
        const files = fs.readdirSync(absolutePath);

        files.forEach(file => {
            let path = absolutePath + '/' + file;

            // if it's not a directory, it will be ignored
            if (fs.lstatSync(path).isDirectory()) {
                if (file == '__tests') {
                    try {
                        fs.rmSync(path, { recursive: true });
                        console.log(`${path} deleted!`);
                    } catch (error) {
                        console.log(`Unable to delete ${path}`);
                    }
                } else {
                    removeDir(path);
                }
            }
        })

    } catch (error) {
        console.log(`${baseDir} is not a directory`);
    }
}

// converts relative path to absolute path.
// if the path is absolute it will return itself
const getAbsolutePath = (baseDir) => path.isAbsolute(baseDir) ? baseDir : path.resolve(baseDir);

removeDir(DIRECTORY); // for a single project
removeMultipleDirs(DIRECTORIES); // for multiple projects
```